# Inkscape: Create a zigzag border/ stroke for an object

Tags: inkscape

It has been asked before for Adobe Illustrator:

[Zigzag border for rectangles](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8172/rounded-rectangle-with-zigzag-border)

[Smooth parallel zigzag lines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/162684/how-to-achieve-this-smooth-zig-zag-effect-for-these-lines)

Is there a way to generate a zigzag border or stroke for a rectangle in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try this.

1. Create one curve with a stroke (with rounded endcaps), duplicate it, flip the duplicate vertically, move together using snapping to snap the two end nodes together.
2. Join the two end nodes together by selecting them and using the Join Select Nodes button [image]  (in the conrol bar along the top)

[image]

2. *Edit > Copy* this joined path to the clipboard
3. Draw a rectangle
4. Add a Pattern Along a Path effect, hit the Link to Path in Clipboard button
5. Choose the "Repeated, Stretched" option
6. Pull the rounded rectangle control down a little to make the corners slightly rounded.

[image]

You can also adjust the width of the pattern using the control point shown here

[image]

Also, since the path an object are now linked in the Path Effect, you can also select and resize, squish or stretch it, and it will automatically apply the changes to the object with the Path Effect.

[image]

More complixity is also possible, here I'm using a combined path for a different effect

[image]